# Spawn and kill node.js child processes in different routes hapi.js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have hapi.js server with two routes. One of it should spawn some child process, and the other one should kill it.

```
var someFunc = require('./module.someFunc')

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');

const { spawn } = require('child_process');

let child

const init = async () => {

 server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path:'/start',
  handler: (request,h) => {
   child = spawn(someFunc());
  }
 })

 server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path:'/stop',
  handler: (request,h) => {
   child.kill('SIGINT');
  }
 })
 await server.start();
}

init();
```

But for some reason I have error in console:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'kill' of undefined`

UPD: Also I'm having an error when firing child process:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object
```

Comment: Make sure you have triggered `/start` beforehand. Also what would happen if one call `start` multiple times?

Comment: is your `someFunc()` returning a file path string?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm pretty sure I've triggered `/start`. For now on if I call it multiple times It jut call's function multiple times (create separate child process, I think). But that's just for testing purposes - ofcourse I want to control each child process independently.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty actually `someFunc()` is returning nothing - it's making a request using external API.
It's also worth mentioning that I have an error when spawn child process - 
`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because `spawn` is throwing an error so `child` variable is ***null***;

---

`spawn` expects a command, you **CANNOT** execute a function with child_process.spawn.

In your case you need to create a new file and make the function there and `fork` it.

**child.js**

```
while(something){
   do something
}
```

Then,

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');
...
server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path:'/start',
  handler: (request,h) => {
   child = fork('child.js');
  }
 })
...
```

Please refer [`this link`](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node) for some simple examples and explanation on how to use `child_process` module

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `fork` method!
Should I still use `child.kill('SIGINT')` when stopping child process?

Comment: Yes it should work, because `fork` and `spawn` both returns child_process instance.